# C++11 initializer_list error

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, initializer-list

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{{"awe", "kjh"}}; // not v{"awe", "kjh"}

    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

1. Is this code erroneous? Or may be it is valid to use double `{}` while initializing vector?
2. I tried this code on gcc and MSVC.
   MSVC 2012 + complier Nov 2012 just cannot compile it, it is not surprising.
   This code compiled with gcc 4.7 or 4.8 gives a **runtime error** during program execution. Is this behavour correct?

Unfortuantely can not test it with other compilers.

Comment: this may be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/c-why-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-are-different

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587436/call-of-overloaded-brace-enclosed-initializer-list-is-ambiguous-how-to-deal-w and http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2238 (they concern something else than this one, but very similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your initialization is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{std::string{"awe", "kjh"}}; 
// not: std::vector<std::string> v{std::string{"awe"}, std::string{"kjh"}};
```

The Standard does not require such a constructor of implementations of type `std::string`, so based on a particular STD implementation, I guess the code can do different things.

Regards,
&rzej

Answer (score 1):

The inner `{}` is being treated a a std::string constructor.
It will fail at runtime if you just do

```
std::string> s{"awe", "kjh"};
```