# Call of overloaded <brace-enclosed initializer list> is ambiguous with inconvertible types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, braced-init-list

Related question:

- [Calling an explicit constructor with a braced-init list: ambiguous or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622076/calling-an-explicit-constructor-with-a-braced-init-list-ambiguous-or-not)

---

The question is similar to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587436/call-of-overloaded-brace-enclosed-initializer-list-is-ambiguous-how-to-deal-w) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587436/call-of-overloaded-brace-enclosed-initializer-list-is-ambiguous-how-to-deal-w), but not the same.

---

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    A();
};
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<double, A> == false);
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<A, double> == false);

void func(std::vector<double> values);
void func(std::vector<A> as);

int main() {
    func({ 4.2 });
}
```

Apparently, `double` and `A` cannot be implicitly converted to each other. So I think `void func(std::vector<double>)` should be called.

But the results for different compilers are different:
https://godbolt.org/z/c1hW47f4c

GCC fails to compile with:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:14:9: error: call of overloaded 'func(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
   14 |     func({ 4.2 });
      |     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:10:6: note: candidate: 'void func(std::vector<double>)'
   10 | void func(std::vector<double> values);
      |      ^~~~
<source>:11:6: note: candidate: 'void func(std::vector<A>)'
   11 | void func(std::vector<A> as);
      |      ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

(VC15 (VS 2017) rejects the example too.)

---

Which one is right? Why?

Comment: This is a bug in GCC.

Comment: It is indeed ill-formed as per the current wording because the second overload `func(std::vector<A>)` will choose explict ctor which isn't allowed in copy list initialization. Though I think intuitively since here another viable option(`func(std::vector<double>)`) is available, the `func(std::vector<A>)` should've been discarded and the first overload `func(std::vector<double>)` should've been used instead of making the program ill-formed. But that is not allowed as per the current wording.

Comment: GCC issue reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113884

Comment: MSVC issue with vector initialization from brace-enclosed initializer list: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-constructor-of-std::vector-selecte/1652923

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr;**

The program is **ill-formed** because during the overload resolution of the call `func({4.2})` for the second overload `func(std::vector<A> as)` the explicit ctor of `std::vector` that takes a `size_t` is choosen which isn't allowed in copy-list-initialization.

##### Language-Lawyer Explanation

###### Step 1

First let us consider the overload resolution for the call `func({4.2})` against the first overload `func(std::vector<double>)`.

Note note that `func({ 4.2 })` is [copy-initialization](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#14):

> **The initialization that occurs in the** = form of a brace-or-equal-initializer or condition ([stmt.select]), **as well as in argument passing**, function return, throwing an exception ([except.throw]), handling an exception ([except.handle]), and aggregate member initialization other than by a designated-initializer-clause ([dcl.init.aggr]), is called copy-initialization.

Now we move onto [dcl.init.general#16](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16) to see that this will use **list initialization**:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows.
> The destination type is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the source type is the type of the initializer expression.
> If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
>
> - **If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list** or is = braced-init-list, **the object or reference is list-initialized ([dcl.init.list])**.

So from [dcl.init.list](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list) we also see that this is **copy-list-initialization**:

> List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list.
> Such an initializer is called an initializer list, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the initializer-list or designated-initializer-clauses of the designated-initializer-list are called the elements of the initializer list.
> An initializer list may be empty.
> List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copy-initialization contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called direct-list-initialization and **list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called copy-list-initialization.** Direct-initialization that is not list-initialization is called direct-non-list-initialization.

Finally we move onto [dcl.init.list#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - Otherwise, **if T is a class type, constructors are considered.
>   The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution** ([over.match], [over.match.list]).
>   If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

This means that overload resolution is done with `std::vector`'s for the argument `{4.2}` and the best one will be choosen.

So we move onto [over.match.list](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list):

> **When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized** such that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed according to the rules in this subclause or when forming a list-initialization sequence according to [over.ics.list], overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - If the initializer list is not empty or T has no default constructor, **overload resolution is first performed where the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T** and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - Otherwise, or **if no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again**, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

Note that since an initializer list ctor was found, so overload resolution won't be performed again.  This in turn means that the initializer list ctor is the choosen option when matching `func({4.2})` against the first overload `func(std::vector<double>)`

###### Step 2

Now we see how `func({4.2})` matches against the second overload `func(std::vector<A>)`.

In this case, almost all the steps are same(as in the last case) except that this time the initializer list ctor `std::vector(std::initializer_list<A>)` is **not viable** and so the statement **if no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again** is satisfied and so

> Otherwise, or if no viable initializer-list constructor is found, **overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T** and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

This means that this time, the `std::size_t` argument ctor of `std::vector` will be choosen. But note that this ctor of `std::vector` is `explicit` and we have:

> **In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.**

Thus the selection of `size_t` argument ctor of `std::vector` makes the program **ill-formed**.

Comment: @273K Yeah, I also don't agree with the closing reason. I'll leave a comment there. Since `std::vector`'s initializer list ctor is also not explicit and neither is `A`'s.

Comment: @273K I've added some references to the standard to explain why it is well-formed.

Comment: @273K They(who closed that issue) are missing that initializer list ctor is preferred over size_t arg ctor. I am sure they will reopen the issue. Anyway I've added the necessary details/references into my answer.

Comment: @273K Note that there is no direct initialization here. Btw the current wording makes the program ill-formed. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Maybe you should keep your discussion link in your answer.

Comment: How do you come from **the initialization is ill-formed** to **the program ill-formed**? IMHO the first one rather is just *such initialization is discarded from the selection*.

Comment: [dcl.init.list] has no role here. Overload resolution happens first, and that requires forming implicit conversion sequences per [over.ics.list] and then comparing them. Both can be formed and neither is better than the other, so this is ill-formed from the ambiguity. We never get to actually performing the initialization, which is where we'd use the rules from [dcl.init.list].

Comment: If the program is ill-formed, and Clang and MSVC [accept it](https://godbolt.org/z/va8G6xsr6), then they contain bugs? Or no diagnostics is required?

Comment: @Fedor Doesn't look IFNDR to me. Just IF. So yes, clang and msvc have bug here.

Comment: Thanks, it is a known Clang bug indeed: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/28016

Comment: @Fedor I see, quite old clang bug it seems.